# Float left wont work - box gets pushed down

Tags: html, push, element, box

I would like put the red box(Block E) below Block C and next to Block D, and at the same time move BLOCK C up with 1% margin between the block A and itself. I've different ways to solve it but all I ended up with was keep failing.. 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhyJ2.png)
Here's my HTML:

```
<body>
  <article>
   <div class="newsblockContainer">
    <div class="blockA">

    </div>
    <div class="blockB">

    </div>
    <div class="blockC">

    </div>
    <div class="blockD">

    </div>
    <div class="blockE">


    </div>
</div>
</article>
            </body>
```

CSS..

```
.newsblockContainer{
        background-color:#000000;
        width:89.2%;
        margin-left:4vw;
        margin-top:3vw;
        height:73.3vw;
        overflow: hidden;

}
.blockA{
        width:59%;
        height:27vw;
        background-color:#FFAE00;
        margin-left:1%;
        margin-top:1%;   
        float:left;  
        position: relative;
    }

.blockB{
        width:38%;
        height:34vw;
        background-color:#FFAE00;
        margin-left:1%;
        margin-top:1%;
        float:left;
        position: relative;
    }
.blockC{
        width:59%;
        height:23vw;
        margin-left:1%;
        float:left;
        background-color:#FFAE00;
        position: relative;
    }
.blockD{    
        height:36.7vw;
        width:38%;
        margin-left:1%;
        background-color:#FFAE00;
        float:left;
        margin-top:1%;
        position:relative;
    }
.blockE{    
        height:15vw;
        background-color:red;
        position: relative;
        margin-top:1%;
        width:59%;
        margin-left: 1%;

}
body{
        background-color:black;
}
article{
        margin-left:12.5%;
        width:75%;
        height:100%;
        background-color:rgba(14,14,14,1.00);

    }
```

Comment: FIDDLE::::: https://jsfiddle.net/j8hg3hf1/12/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
Please edit the question for the purpose of providing additional useful information, instead of commenting your own question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, start by taking the **2-minutes tour of StackOverflow** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour); seriously, it'll help you :-)

Here's an updated version that works; I made some of the blocks float right, and also, readjusted the margins. Check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/j8hg3hf1/15/).

```
.blockB {
    /* Rest of the code */
    margin-right: 1%;
    float:right;
    /* Rest of the code */
}
```

And:

```
.blockC {
  /* Rest of the code */
  margin-top: 1%;
  float: left;
  /* Rest of the code */
}

.blockD {
  /* Rest of the code */
  margin-right: 1%;
  background-color: #FFAE00;
  float: right;
  /* Rest of the code */
}
```

I also removed the `position` properties, as they were not needed (*maybe you'll do something with them later on.*) I would suggest you to use **absolute positioning**, or even, consider using **Flexbox**. They might be more appropriate for your use case than using floats, but that depends on what you want, anyways.
Hope it helps.